# Как изменить цвет иконки в CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, вёрстка, svg

Отрывок кода на React JS:

```
return (
        <div className="navbar">
            <div>
                {
                    navobj.map((el)=>
                    <button className="btn" key={el.obj.title} >
                        <img className="svgEl" src={el.obj.svg}/>
                        <p className="pEl">{el.obj.title}</p>
                    </button>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

и стили к нему:

```
.svgEl {
    
    stroke: #9EA4B7 !important;
}
```

Все подключения и импорты правильные, но иконка не хочет менять свой цвет, даже если убрать из path заданное свойство stroke.
Приблизительно как выглядит эта svg иконка:

```
<svg width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 28 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="" stroke="#9EA4B7" stroke-width="2.5" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Что вы конкретно хотите изменить? `stroke` - отвечает за обводку, `fill` за наполнение. У вас `fill="none"`, то есть если вам нужно установить заливку для svg задавайте цвет для `fill`

Comment: хочу изменить `stroke`

Comment: Вы уверены, что в `el.obj.svg` лежит svg? Просто как то странно, что вы ее в img запихиваете. Что бы отобразить svg , достаточно сделать так: `{el.obj.svg}` в рендере

Comment: у svg подключенного как обычная картинка (через тэг img) нельзя менять заливку и обводку. Для этого ее нужно вставить инлайново - т.е. так импортировать `import {ReactComponent as Cart} from "./cart.svg"` и вставить  {Cart}

Comment: дело в том, что у меня не одна иконка, а несколько, отсюда такое странное отображение через img. Плюс webpack конфиг свой не настроен, так вроде можно использовать svgr. Надеялась, что есть еще какой-нибудь способ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То как вы реализовали вывод иконки не даст вам возможность сменить внутренний параметр `stroke` для иконки. Выводите данный объект инлайново на страницу. Тогда будет возможность достучаться через `CSS`

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}
.svg_icon{
    stroke: #9EA4B7;
}

svg:hover  .svg_icon{
    stroke: #f00;
}
```

```html
<svg  width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 28 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle class="svg_icon" cx="28" cy="28" r="14"/>
</svg>
```